# Render a table with an if condition in react

Tags: reactjs, if-statement

I want to render a table in react redux. To be more specific I have an accounts JSON array like this with 1- records:

```
[
{
    "size": "100",
    "date": "6/1/2017",
    "time": "09:23 AM",
    "status": "Working"
  },
{
    "size": "100",
    "date": "6/1/2017",
    "time": "09:23 AM",
    "status": "Completed"
  },
]
```

and I want to render the record with status Completed. So when I create my render Table function I write:

```
if ((ordersTrades.map(orderTrade => orderTrade.status)) === 'Completed') {
 return (
   ...
      );
}
```

But it does not return anything. ordersTrades is the name of my JSON. Why is that?

Comment: map return array [] === 'Completed' // false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it like this, first `filter` the items that have status 'Completed', then use the map on that to `render` the `html`:

```js
a = [
{
    "size": "100",
    "date": "6/1/2017",
    "time": "09:23 AM",
    "status": "Working"
  },
{
    "size": "100",
    "date": "6/1/2017",
    "time": "09:23 AM",
    "status": "Completed"
  },
]

b = a.filter(el=> el.status === 'Completed' )

console.log(b); // items that have status Completed

a.filter(el=> el.status === 'Completed' ).map(el=>{console.log('date', el.date) /*return here*/})
```

Answer (score 1):

First filter the array to get the items you need, then use map for rendering as usual:

```
ordersTrades.filter( order => order.status === "Completed" ).map( order => (
  /* render the item */
))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1h03gdzy/1/